# Desktop PC with External Hard Drive only

Tags: computer-building

Is it <s>possible</s> feasible to assemble a desktop PC that only uses an external hard drive (i.e. with no separate internal hard drive) ? The idea is to be able to carry my data with me all the time without having to copy between external and internal drives.

If this can be done, what kind of connector do I use between the external hard drive and the motherboard (external drives <s>only</s> mostly have USB connectors)?

Update: From @Ramhound's comment, it seems that relying on a USB connector will result in poor performance. This might be fixed using a Seagate GoFlex drive which has support for an eSATA connector. Is this feasible? Can the eSATA connector withstand repeated plugging/unplugging?

Comment: Its not accurate to say all external drives only use USB connectors.  You wouldn't use any connectors, just modify the boot order, but it would be slow on anything except eSATA

Comment: Are there external drives supporting eSATA? I couldn't find any from well-known brands.

Comment: OK. I just found Seagate GoFlex. http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=OzR4YRu-Jk4 Can I use such a drive as the sole HDD on a desktop PC?

Comment: Have you tried?

Comment: Nope. Don't have access to such a drive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like the comments above said eSATA is the way to go. To address your update question, eSATA is designed for a lifetime of [5000 parings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Esata#eSATA) (vs the 50 the internal SATA connector has and the [1500 USB has](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB#Standard_connectors))

One other thing you should note, depending on what OS you are using you may not be able to use the USB drive as the boot sequence of some OS's will re-initialize all USB devices during startup, this can be a problem if the OS is not fully in memory when this happens as the drive will go offline briefly. I know for sure this is a problem with XP and will cause bluescreens on boot, but I don't know if it still happens on Vista or newer.

Edit: It looks like from your question you where having a hard time finding eSATA drives, [here is a Newegg search listing all of the eSATA external drives available](http://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductList.aspx?Submit=Property&Subcategory=414&N=100023376%20600484061%20600484014%20600484012%20600484065%20600484050%20600484040%20600484025%20600484018%20600484043&IsNodeId=1&IsPowerSearch=1).

Comment: So, I will be connecting an eSATA port to the motherboard correct? And connecting the drive to that port. Right? (I have never assembled a PC in my life).

Comment: there will be a eSATA port on the back, near where you would plug in the headphones or the network cable. You also could have one on the front if your case supports it, if so you would need to wire the front panel connector to your motherboard with the supplied cables that came with your case.